# How to manually initialize R terminal in vscode?

Tags: r, visual-studio-code

## Background

My current scene is this:

I use vscode to log in to the `login node` and then use `R: Create R terminal` to generates an R terminal running on the `login node`, but the `login node` has poor performance. So I usually use vscode to log in to the `login node`, and then ssh to the `computing node` which cannot log in directly from the local.

When I ssh to the `computing node`, the R terminal generated by using `R: Create R terminal` again is still on the `login node`, not on the `computing node`. So if I want to use R in the `computing node`, I can only manually type `R` or `radian`, but then I can't link it with current vscode, and I can't use vscode to show `R plot`.

## Try

I've tried running all the R scripts in the R extension in vscode, but none of them enable manual initialization of the R terminal.

## HELP

Does anyone know how to manually initialize the R terminal, please tell me the principle, or teach me how to manually initialize, looking forward to the help of the big guys.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: 'I can only ssh to the computing node first, and then enable radian' sounds like manually initialising the R terminal to me. Can you provide a bit more information about what you would like to happen (e.g., which commands you would like to be able to use, what happens when you try it currently)?

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the setting `R: Always Use Active Terminal`. Don't use the command `R: Create R terminal`. Commands should now use your computing node instead of your login node.